# Convert to ES6 export default from module.exports with spreads

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

As per https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039, when mixing import with module.exports, upgrading Webpack to >= 2.2 leads to the follow type error:

> Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'

Okay, change module.exports to export default { ... }, but how to convert the following with spreads so that each of the exports from the import are actually exported.

How to convert:

```
import * as authActions from './auth';
import * as someOtherActions from './someOther';

module.exports = {
  ...authActions,
  ...someOtherActions,
};
```

To ES6 (since the following doesn't export all the including actions via the spread):

```
import authActions from './auth';
import someOtherActions from './someOther';

export default {
  ...authActions,
  ...someOtherActions,
};
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, was the `export default` with `...` throwing an error for you, or just silently failing? It should be a syntax error, so something in your tooling is likely making it parse when it shouldn't.

Comment: Silently failing. Syntax error only occurs with export { ...foo, ...bar } so my webpack/babel/eslint combo isn't catching it.

Comment: And thanks for the response! Didn't get the magic combo of keywords to find the other question you answered.

Comment: Oh you know, the question I linked to said they didn't get a syntax error so I was confused, but your case actually isn't a syntax error, it's just not what you want, so my mistake there.